# localhost opens folder structure instead of main page - WAMP

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

my localhost wamp page was working fine but due to some reason it opens the /index of page.
[image]

I need to get the main home page back. I have seen some solutions to the previous answers but all my settings are exactly as advised.
"LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so" is uncommented in the httpd.conf file.
Any help on this would be amazing.
Apache version is 2.4.41
OS: Windows 10

Cheers!

Comment: looks like you deleted a few files from the www folder, are they in yoru recycle folder?

Comment: I don't think I deleted anything but it started working after reinstalling wamp. Thank you.